# What controls responsiveness in Wordpress?

Tags: css, responsive

I am testing a WP install along with a custom theme made by third parties. The theme per se is responsive, however in some situations, at particular resolutions,  parts of the page will be blank although it looks like there would be enough space to fit objects. For instance take a look [here](http://me-about.me/test/) (the 3 columns below the main slider) and using Chrome Dev Tools, you will see that switching to mobile view and shrinking the window, at 780px the browser will adjust page showing only one column on the left, leaving a large amount of blank space.

I am wondering if there are some Wordpress-related settings or it is just a matter of CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has absolutely nothing to do with responsiveness, neither does themes or plugins. Responsiveness is controlled by media queries (*CSS*) set in stylesheets and the particular browser the site is viewed in. It is here where screen sizes are determined and checked against available media query rules.

Just one note, older browsers like IE6, 7 and 8 does not support media queries and are therefor not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

It's all down to the theme and possibly any elements on your page that are generated by plugins, which are hard for theme authors to anticipate sometimes.

Comment: Thank you. If you were to debug this what would you look for? Just the CSS?

Comment: I also wonder if there are some best practices when dealing with this. For example, it may be a bad idea to split the page in odd parts?

Comment: @Riccardo no problem. It can all depend a bit on the exact elements on the page, but usually I find I can make some fresh CSS override the bits of layout that I don't like. If you've got a way of adding your own CSS, perhaps using a child theme, hooking in an extra CSS file using your own plugin or using an existing plugin, then by looking in your Dev tools you can probably work out some fixes.

Comment: I am overriding with child CSS. Is think that splitting the page in odd numbers is a bad idea. What do you think?

Comment: @Riccardo do you mean the sections with three columns? It can be tricky, but at tablet sizes you could have welcome go full width with photo to the left of the text followed by two columns and then have the testimonials go full width with photos to the side of the text. Then on smartphone sizes have them all single column.

Answer (score 0):

The platform itself does not control responsiveness of your website. It depends on how you write the CSS code, that runs on your theme.

If you have created additional CSS files, make sure to include them in main functions file of the theme with:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```